# Como se usa o NotifyIcon no C# Form

Tags: c#

Alguém me pode explicar como funciona o **NotifyIcon** ?

Comment: O que precisa saber?

Comment: Na verdade o intuito do site é que você primeiro faça a sua pesquisa, tente implementar e retorne com uma dúvida específica ou com algum problema que você não consegui resolver

Comment: O NotifyIcon cria um ícone na tray do Windows (aquela parte perto do relógio)